Specify a key-binding using :bind in use-package with a variable passed in from ORG table
I'm attempting to centralize my key-binds in my org-literate Emacs config, that expands out to a series of use-package declarations. The issue I'm having is with the passing of keys as variables into the :bind specifications. If I do the same bind with evil-define-key or bind-key in the :config block it works, but I'd prefer to use the more idiomatic :bind, if possible, or find out, why that is is not possible.
Edit after first answer: I had read in the documentation "where KEY is a string" , but then, why does my workaround with :config work?
Why can't I just wrap the variable with a ,(symbol-value or ,(cons call in the :bind part?
Here's 2 examples with working and non-working syntax:
** Ace-Jump                                                        :JUMP:NAV:
#+NAME: USE-PACKAGE-ace-jump-mode
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var acejmp=Table-Keys[3,1]
(use-package ace-jump-mode :ensure t
  :config
  (bind-key acejmp 'ace-jump-mode)  ;; Bind ace-jump-mode to the desired keys
; The following ways to specify the bind do not work ?!
;   :bind
;   (acejmp . ace-jump-mode)          ; This would be the preferred form
;   (,(cons (acejmp 'ace-jump-mode))) ; Even this would be better than the above
)
#+END_SRC

*** Vimish-Fold                                                        :FOLD:
#+NAME: USE-PACKAGE-vimish-fold
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var fold-stuff=Table-Keys[4,1]
(use-package vimish-fold :ensure t
; These lines work, but I want to pass the Key as variable "fold-stuff"
;  :bind (:map evil-visual-state-map
;              ("<XF86Launch5>" . vimish-fold)
;         :map evil-normal-state-map
;              ("<XF86Launch5>" . vimish-fold-toggle)  )
  :after evil
; This way to pass "XF86Launch6" as variable "fold-stuff" works:
  :config (evil-define-key 'normal org-mode-map
                           (kbd fold-stuff) #'vimish-fold-toggle)
          (evil-define-key 'visual org-mode-map
                           (kbd fold-stuff) #'vimish-fold)
)
#+END_SRC

Can somebody tell me, what I'm doing wrong in my :bind-attempts. or why this is not possible? Is it possible/needed to somehow "extend" :bind to accept variables?

You can’t. Reread the documentation:
To bind keys globally, the ‘:bind’ keyword takes as its argument either
a single cons or a list of conses.  Each cons has the form
‘(KEY . COMMAND)’, where KEY is a string indicating the key to bind, and
COMMAND is the name of a command (a symbol).  The syntax for the keys is
similar to the syntax used by the ‘kbd’ function (see *note (emacs)Init
Rebinding::, for more information).

use-package is a macro that expects to get a particular syntax, and it doesn’t try to evaluate what you give it. It requires you to give it a string, and a variable name is not a string.
